# EF Core - DbContext.SaveChangesAsync() not persisting data in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm experiencing odd behaviour on a quite simple task. I'm using EF Core 2.1 with SQL Server 2016, I have the following code that basically creates three objects and inserts them into the database using DbContext.Add().

And all three Add() operations return successfully, with properly created entities, however, the **JobSchedule** is never inserted into the database when calling SaveChangesAsync(), and I have no clue.

```
private async Task CreateXPTOJob(XPTOJobModel model)
{
    var jobData = new XPTOJobData
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Foo = model.Foo,
        Bar= model.Bar
    };

    Context.XPTOJobData.Add(jobData);

    var jobType = await Context.JobTypes.FindByCode(EJobType.XPTO);
    var jobPriority = await Context.JobPriorities.FindByCode(EJobPriority.Normal);
    var jobStatus = await Context.JobStatuses.FindByCode(EJobStatus.Created);

    var job = new Job
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        OwnerId = UserId,
        PriorityId = jobPriority.Id,
        TypeId = jobType.Id,
        StatusId = jobStatus.Id,
        MaxRetries = 3,
        XPTOJobDataId = jobData.Id
    };

    Context.Jobs.Add(job);

    var scheduleFrequency = await Context.ScheduleFrequencies.FindByCode(EScheduleFrequency.Once);

    var schedule = new JobSchedule
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Enabled = true,
        FrequencyId = scheduleFrequency.Id,
        JobId = jobId,
        NotifyCompletion = true,
        PreferredStartTime = DateTime.Now
    };

    Context.JobSchedules.Add(schedule);

    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If a look at the debug output, I can see the four Selects, and two inserts, as bellow:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[@__type_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [jobType].[Id], [jobType].[Code], [jobType].[Description], [jobType].[DisplayName], [jobType].[Name]
FROM [JobQueue].[JobTypes] AS [jobType]
WHERE [jobType].[Code] = @__type_0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__priority_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [jobPriority].[Id], [jobPriority].[Code], [jobPriority].[Description], [jobPriority].[DisplayName], [jobPriority].[Name]
FROM [JobQueue].[JobPriorities] AS [jobPriority]
WHERE [jobPriority].[Code] = @__priority_0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [jobStatus].[Id], [jobStatus].[Code], [jobStatus].[Description], [jobStatus].[DisplayName], [jobStatus].[Name]
FROM [JobQueue].[JobStatuses] AS [jobStatus]
WHERE [jobStatus].[Code] = @__status_0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__frequency_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [scheduleFrequency].[Id], [scheduleFrequency].[Code], [scheduleFrequency].[Description], [scheduleFrequency].[DisplayName], [scheduleFrequency].[Name]
FROM [JobQueue].[ScheduleFrequencies] AS [scheduleFrequency]
WHERE [scheduleFrequency].[Code] = @__frequency_0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Guid), @p1='?' (DbType = Guid), @p2='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [LifeCycle].[XPTOJobData] ([Id], [Foo], [Bar])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p3='?' (DbType = Guid), @p4='?' (DbType = Guid), @p5='?' (DbType = Int32), @p6='?' (DbType = Guid), @p7='?' (DbType = Guid), @p8='?' (DbType = Guid), @p9='?' (DbType = Guid), @p10='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [JobQueue].[Jobs] ([Id], [YPTOJobDataId], [MaxRetries], [XPTOJobDataId], [OwnerId], [PriorityId], [StatusId], [TypeId])
VALUES (@p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10);

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method JobQueue.Controllers.JobsController.Post (JobQueue), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 63.4302ms.
```

All the **FindByCode** extensions follow the same logic:

```
public static Task<ScheduleFrequency> FindByCode(this IQueryable<ScheduleFrequency> queryable, EScheduleFrequency frequency)
{
    return queryable.AsNoTracking().SingleAsync(scheduleFrequency => scheduleFrequency.Code == frequency);
}
```

Any ideas why the third insert is not being executed? I've tried a lot of small changes and tweaks, but unsuccessfully. Anyways, thank you for your time and help!

**Edit 1:** I'm putting more related code bellow.

DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<XPTOJobData> XPTOJobData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobPriority> JobPriorities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobSchedule> JobSchedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobStatus> JobStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobType> JobTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ScheduleFrequency> ScheduleFrequencies { get; set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new XPTOJobDataConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobPriorityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobScheduleConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobStatusConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ScheduleFrequencyConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Job

```
public class Job
{
    // Properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? XPTOJobDataId { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Guid PriorityId { get; set; }
    public Guid StatusId { get; set; }
    public Guid TypeId { get; set; }
    public ushort MaxRetries { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public XPTOJobData XPTOJobData { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public JobPriority Priority { get; set; }
    public JobStatus Status { get; set; }
    public JobType Type { get; set; }

    // Navigation Related Properties
    public ICollection<JobSchedule> JobSchedules => _jobSchedules?.ToList();
    private HashSet<JobSchedule> _jobSchedules;

    public Job()
    {
        _jobSchedules = new HashSet<JobSchedule>();
    }
}
```

JobPriority

```
public enum EJobPriority
{
    Normal,
    High,
    Immediate
}

public class JobPriority
{
    // Properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public EJobPriority Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation Related Properties
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs => _jobs?.ToList();
    private HashSet<Job> _jobs;

    public JobPriority()
    {
        _jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
    }
}
```

JobSchedule

```
public class JobSchedule
{
    // Properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public Guid FrequencyId { get; set; }
    public Guid JobId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NextRunDate { get; set; }
    public bool NotifyCompletion { get; set; }
    public DateTime PreferredStartTime { get; set; }
    public string Recurrence { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public Job Job { get; set; }
    public ScheduleFrequency Frequency { get; set; }
}
```

JobConfiguration

```
public class JobConfiguration : AEntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    protected override string TableName => "Jobs";
    protected override string SchemaName => Schemas.JobQueue;

    protected override void ConfigureForeignKeys(EntityTypeBuilder<Job> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(job => job.XPTOJobData)
            .WithMany()
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("XPTOJobDataId"))
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

        entity.HasOne(job => job.Owner)
            .WithMany(user => user.Jobs)
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("OwnerId"))
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        entity.HasOne(job => job.Priority)
            .WithMany(jobPriority => jobPriority.Jobs)
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("PriorityId"))
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        entity.HasOne(job => job.Status)
            .WithMany(jobStatus => jobStatus.Jobs)
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("StatusId"))
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        entity.HasOne(job => job.Type)
            .WithMany(jobType => jobType.Jobs)
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("TypeId"))
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

JobPriorityConfiguration

```
public class JobPriorityConfiguration : AEntityTypeConfiguration<JobPriority>
{
    protected override string TableName => "JobPriorities";
    protected override string SchemaName => Schemas.JobQueue;

    protected override void ConfigureProperties(EntityTypeBuilder<JobPriority> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(jobPriority => jobPriority.Code)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(jobPriority => jobPriority.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(jobPriority => jobPriority.DisplayName)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(jobPriority => jobPriority.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureIndexes(EntityTypeBuilder<JobPriority> entity)
    {
        entity.HasIndex(x => x.Code)
            .IsUnique()
            .HasName(CreateUniqueKeyName("Code"));

        entity.HasIndex(x => x.Name)
            .IsUnique()
            .HasName(CreateUniqueKeyName("Name"));
    }
}
```

JobScheduleConfiguration

```
public class JobScheduleConfiguration : AEntityTypeConfiguration<JobSchedule>
{
    protected override string TableName => "JobSchedules";
    protected override string SchemaName => Schemas.JobQueue;

    protected override void ConfigureProperties(EntityTypeBuilder<JobSchedule> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(jobSchedule => jobSchedule.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .IsRequired();

        entity.Property(jobSchedule => jobSchedule.Recurrence)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }

    protected override void ConfigureIndexes(EntityTypeBuilder<JobSchedule> entity)
    {
        entity.HasIndex(jobSchedule => jobSchedule.Name)
            .HasName(CreateIndexName("Name"));
    }

    protected override void ConfigureForeignKeys(EntityTypeBuilder<JobSchedule> entity)
    {
        entity.HasOne(jobSchedule => jobSchedule.Job)
            .WithMany(job => job.JobSchedules)
            .HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("JobId"))
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Long shot, but try without `AsNoTracking` there. Shouldn't make a difference, but with ef-core you never can tell...

Comment: I just tried this instant, and now I'm getting an exception:

`The association between entity types 'JobPriority' and 'Job' has been severed but the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.  Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.`

Comment: We're going to need the code of the involved classes as well. I wonder how an association can be severed by adding a `ScheduleFrequency` to the change tracker.

Comment: To be really specific, the exception occurred on the first insert of the SaveChangesAsync, so no entity was ever inserted into the database this time.
About the rest of the code, because there's at least 10 files involved, I don't know how to proceed here, should I create a git repo and put the code there? or just paste and copy in the description? By the way, thanks so far for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit wary of these off-site resources. But maybe you can first try to only get the required ID *values* from the db (`PriorityId` etc.), that is, without querying the entire entities. If that works at least you have a work-around. Well, it's better anyway because the queries become much leaner that way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That actually corrected the exception, and I went full circle the the initial problem. I'll updated the description with the rest of the code.

By the way, I made all FindByCode like this: 

`return queryable.Where(scheduleFrequency => scheduleFrequency.Code == frequency).Select(scheduleFrequency => scheduleFrequency.Id).SingleAsync();`

Comment: Well, it was a proof o concept project i order to migrate from EF6 to EF Core... and so far it's being painful. I added some extra code to see if it helps solving the problem. It's utterly frustrating see something so simple not working.

Comment: I've just noticed you didn't ignore runtime properties in the mapping, and also you did not specify a mapping for the Frequency property. It's a long shot, but maybe .SaveChangesAsync swallows exceptions and does not wrap the whole action within one transaction.

Comment: The Frequency property mapping missing was definitively a mistake, but its correction had no effect on the problem. I'm starting have the same filling of "swallowed exceptions". Sorry, but I just didn't get what you meant with "runtime properties in the mapping", may you elaborate?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `public ICollection<JobSchedule> JobSchedules => _jobSchedules?.ToList();`.. this must be an EF6 thing, I've never seen it before. Is this supposed to load any `JobSchedules` that are already in the change tracker in to the `Job`?

Comment: @AdamVincent That, and `=> _jobs?.ToList()`, is definitely something that should be changed. These properties should be regular auto properties. This code causes all kinds of trouble of which the observed issue may be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your side effect is being caused by the properties following this signature.

`public ICollection<JobSchedule> JobSchedules => _jobSchedules?.ToList();`

DbSet properties of `virtual ICollection<>` no longer means the same thing. This does not enable lazy loading of the navigation property. You must enable it in the DbContext configuration.

---

**Additional takeaways**

According to the content of the post, you are making a proof of concept that EF 6 can be migrated to EF Core.  I think the cause of your problems are side effect behaviors.  EF Core focuses on a convention first approach, whereas EF 6 requires verbose configuration. Let those conventions do the work for you.

For instance, your classes (the ones that you have shared) deriving from `AEntityTypeConfiguration<>` are *almost* completely restating the default conventions, with the exception of the explicit naming of the Foreign Key Restraint.  `.HasConstraintName(CreateForeignKeyName("XPTOJobDataId"))` If you have the ability to switch to EF Core's Fkey naming scheme, then that's a lot of code that does not need to be written. At least 3 classes and an interface would not need to be written.

Comment: Yes sir, you are indeed correct. I've only worked with database first on EF6 and had to look out for several tutorials. One one them had a pretty compelling  argument for the use of the `public ICollection<JobSchedule> JobSchedules => _jobSchedules?.ToList();`, but I don't quiet remeber right now. As soon as I removed all of them, the code worked perfectly. Regarding the "restating the default convetions", I'm gonna have a good look about the conventions, because nobody should rewrite useless code. Thank you for your time, and for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @marceloatg Maybe next time it's a good idea to show all relevant code up front. I couldn't have guessed these uncommon properties (note to self: *It is a capital mistake to theorize before you have all the evidence.* - Sherlock Holmes)